# django occasionally throwing a NoReverseMatch

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I'm getting an occasional error in django template rendering; I *sometimes* get a NoReverseMatch on the following URL:

```
    url(r'^student-agreement/(?P<code>[\w:-]+)$',
        StudentAgreementView.as_view(),
        name='student-agreement'),
```

The `code` argument is created by calling `signing.dumps()` on the object ID, which creates a string such as `'MjExMg:1Z0H6s:1H19SjhO2CCAlAUgkiYLvyYLSzI'` - as far as I can tell, this should match the regex provided. However, trying a test like:

```
for i in range(20)
    print reverse('student-agreement', kwargs={'code':signing.dumps(i)})
```

will throw an NoReverseMatch pretty quickly.

Here is a sample Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/sis_esv_repo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2883, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-58-f02835044aa6>", line 2, in <module>
    print reverse('student-agreement', kwargs={'code':signing.dumps(i)})
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/sis_esv_repo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 551, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/sis_esv_repo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 468, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'student-agreement' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'code': 'Mg:1Z0H9L:ltHc7mAAteN7jBHRBIuT-Zbzt18'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['school/student-agreement/(?P<code>[\\w:-_]+)$']
```

Comment: Hey, the regex you posted `(?P<code>[\w:-]+)$` is different than the regex in the traceback  `(?P<code>[\\w:-_]+)$ `

Comment: @fasouto - I can only guess that when printing it out in the traceback, python uses normal string representation, rather than raw mode https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#raw-string-notation - but also, it works some of the time, and not other times.

Comment: @fasouto - my mistake - I hadn't noticed the extra underscore there, just the backslash. So the tests I was running were using a debug session that still had my old regex `[\w:-_]` there. While trying to work out what was wrong, I realised the underscore was not necessary as the `\w` includes underscore. After restarting my debugging session, I can't get it to fail this way anymore. Which is strange, as I would have expected the regexes `[\w:-]` and `[\w:-_]` to be identical.

Comment: Oh damn; `[:-_]` gets all of the characters from `:` to `_` - if using a hyphen in a regex set of characters, it has to be the last item. So `[\w:_-]` would work, but `[\w:-_]` does not

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the regex I was using while running the tests was slightly different to the one I posted in the question - I hadn't reloaded my instance, and it was using the old regex I had been using: `(?P<code>[\w:-_]+)`. The correct regex is `(?P<code>[\w:-]+)` - the `:-_` makes the regex match the range from : to _ but doesn't include the hyphen itself. The correct regex has they hyphen at the end of the set, so it is treated just as a hyphen character. Since the `\w` includes an underscore, the underscore is not necessary, but `(?P<code>[\w:_-]+)` would also be a correct regex.

Thanks to @fasouto for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score -1):

The output produces `_` characters too.

Comment: I did initially have _ in the regex but it had the same issues. After some investigation, I found in the python docs: \w
When the LOCALE and UNICODE flags are not specified, matches any alphanumeric character and the underscore; this is equivalent to the set [a-zA-Z0-9_]. With LOCALE, it will match the set [0-9_] plus whatever characters are defined as alphanumeric for the current locale. If UNICODE is set, this will match the characters [0-9_] plus whatever is classified as alphanumeric in the Unicode character properties database.